# Securing the archipelago before expanding the radar in Boom Beach

Tags: boom-beach

I’m no longer expanding the radar in Boom Beach but only defending the archipelago. Is it possible to secure the area to the point where one is no longer attacked before expanding to new areas?

Comment: Why would you want to do that bro? This wouldn't provide any advantages. Just expand and get more bases. More bases means, better chances to get defeatable enemies. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to clear out the entire area of NPC and player bases, but it is extremely difficult because it will often place higher level players in your viewable area and because the fewer attacks there are in your range, the faster new attacks show up. Personally, I quickly found it was too difficult to clear out the entire area and maintain it like that before expanding, because I would often try to replace a high level opponent only to have it replaced by another high level opponent that I was unable to defeat.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever did secure all the bases, when you came back the next day, there would be more bases. Besides, what's the point.

Comment: This seems like a very good answer, but keep in mind, this is not a forum; Complete answers and descriptive explanations are recommended.

Comment: "'Besides, what's the point." That actually sounds like a question you should be asking, because there is a point. A few of them, in fact.